# Cocoa NSTextView Text not showing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an `IBOutlet` set up in my header file. I also have a `NSTextField` object in my window. I tried editing it using:

```
[_chapterContent insertText:@"Hi"];
```

and I have a function to run it but it's not showing up. Why? Am I missing anything?

In my header file, I have:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSTextView *chapterContent;
```

In my implementation file:

```
[_chapterContent insertText:@"Hi"];
```

Comment: thank you guys for your help!!! I simply just deleted it and reconnected again! But thanks very very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`[self.chapterContent insertText:@"Hi"]`

instead of

`[_chapterContent insertText:@"Hi"]`.

Hope it´s help